# Ever since vs since

Tags: sentence-meaning

Let's say you kissed a co-worker, after that you have been thinking of her incessantly. You say:

> **Ever since** the day we kissed, I can't stop thinking about you.

Or

> **Since** the day we kissed, I can't stop thinking about you.

What is difference between the two? (Sentence meaning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ever since" is very idiomatic in this circumstance. It is such a common expression that it wouldn't occur to me (or most other people, I think) to start out that sentence with just plain "Since". However, either way is grammatical, and perfectly good English.

"*Ever since* the day we kissed ..." sounds slightly more emphatic/dramatic than simply "*Since* the day we kissed ...", but other than that both sentences have the very same meaning, and both sound fine.